# WordPress function to format date in Advanced Custom Field

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, function, date

Any help will be appreciated.  I am a bit of a newbie in all of this and this is my first ever question :).

I have created a site for a client using the WordPress Advanced Custom Field plugin http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/. I am having trouble displaying the from and to dates of holiday packages in a specific format.  The site can be viewed at http://www.vikodesigns.co.za/travelmauritius

Both fields are in a versatile format created with the jQuery date picker using yyyymmdd as I need to order them ascending by the from date.  The client wants to display the from date as 'd M' (01 Jan) and the to date as 'd M Y' (31 Jan 2015).

I need to write a WordPress function to do this in my child theme functions.php to use it everywhere these two values are displayed.

The to date value is 'valid_date_from' and the from value is 'valid_date_to'.  The values are added to the page builder with the shortcodes [valid_date_from] and [acf field="valid_date_to"].

In the page builder the code looks like this:

```
<div class="packagesDates">Valid from [acf field="valid_date_from"] - [acf field="valid_date_to"]</div>
```

Any ideas on how a WordPress function would be written for this?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised the versatile date format used to add the dates is yymmdd.

Comment: it looks like its already in correct format. [check this image](https://www.anonimg.com/img/3bdad0cae23e241f1fca50e8f6d52d1c.png) . Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Hi Cerlin. Thank you for the quick response. I have made the change to the date format on a few pages after I realised I needed to use the versatile date format for sorting purposes.  I have not made the change to all of the packages yet.  The one hotel page has been done.  Check it at http://vikodesigns.co.za/travelmauritius/accommodation/resorts-and-hotels/coin-de-mire-attitude/ . Thank you.

Comment: Anyone out there who can help me with this function?